# Codigo no se actualiza en el navegador

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un desarrollo en JavaScript y html. Es un widget, el cual, estoy probando su funcionamiento en un servidor remoto.
Mi problema, es que a veces pasa, que cuando cambio el código fuente del javascript, y lo copio en el servidor, al momento de ejecutar la aplicación, en el explorador, el código no se actualiza, y sigue usando un código anterior.
Lamentablemente esto no sucede con todos los archivos (otros widgets).
He tenido que llegar a borrar todo el sitio, y reemplazarlo con el código de mi maquina de desarrollo para que tome los cambios.
Esto sucede con Chrome, y con Edge.
Alguien mas tiene este mismo problema? o sabe por que sucede?
Gracias por su tiepo.

Comment: Eso sucede por la cache del propio navegador. En estos casos suelo pulsar la tecla Shift mientras pulso el botón de Actualizar/Recarga en el navegador para forzar la recarga de todos los archivos saltándose la cache.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta.. efectivamente limpie el cache de mi equipo, y ahora se actualizo el codigo.. Sabes si existe la forma para que no se guarde en cache los archivos con los cuales estoy trabajando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega estas etiquetas `meta` entre las etiquetas `<head>` de tus archivos `HTML`

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
</head>
```

Con estas etiquetas el navegador del cliente no tendrá en cuenta la caché almacenada

Comment: Gracias.!! funciono a la perfeccion